# What is the framework used for sites with app.domain.com/something address?

Tags: web-applications

I see a lot of web apps with this kind of address and I'm wondering what is the framework used to create it.

examples:

app.sparkpost.com/dashboard
app.neverbounce.com/lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know what framework is used based on the domain name. Sometimes the complete url (for example `wp-admin` for WordPress) gives some information, but not always.

You can use https://wappalyzer.com/ to see what kind of tools (framework, front end tools, back end server) are being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell what backend framework is used only by looking at the address. A lot of frameworks let you define that kind of behaviour.

Even most well-known ones lets you do this, for example with Apache you can use the [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) mod.

Comment: What about the FE?

Comment: Front-End frameworks ? You can know which ones are used by just looking at the page's code in almost any browser (Ctrl+U inChrome for example, or F12 to open the dev tools). But if you're talking about responding to calls to like `app.sparkpost.com/dashboard`, the front-end framework usually has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Can you tell for example what app.sparkpost.com/dashboard uses? I would like to do something similar using this kind of FE together with AWS services (Lambda, DynamoDB), that is why I'm asking. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what they use, and I don't know the company at all. Maybe they have a blog or something where they describe their architecture ? I don't really get what you want to build, but tbh I think really any recent framework can handle this. Try to look for "routing" or "URL rewriting".